# How to come back or redirect to first screen once we click on OK Button to print the smartform?

Tags: abap, sap-smart-forms

I have created one Smart Form and everything is working fine. The problem is - There are two options while printing the Smart Form (1. Print Preview and 2. Print).

Now when I click on print preview it shows the Smart Form which is created and then I click on Print option which is present above in SAP GUI screen then I get the pop-up of printer and once I click on OK button on the same pop-up then it should redirect back to the first screen where I had provided Document Number to get the Smart Form (for ex. Below code)

`PARAMETERS : P_MATNR TYPE MARA-MATNR`

Comment: `it should redirect back to the first screen` who said you so?

Comment: What you describe is the standard behavior, which you can't customize. Why would you want to make this Smart Form printing behavior different from all other Smart Forms?

Comment: Once I click on OK button then smartform is printing. Then after that it should go back to main screen or main selection screen. Or Can I do this using Enhancement ?